# (Value,Index) pair range filter based on index

Tags: scala

I am looking for a way to get all the pair from the given data structure Array[Array[(String, Int)]] based on range criteria.

To clarify more: consider the example:

```
val block= Array(Array(("foo",0),("bar",1),("foobar",2),("barfoo",3)),Array(("FOO",0),("BAR",1),("FOOBAR",2),("BARFOO",3),("FOOFOO",4)))
```

I  would like to get the String Array from index  3 onwards like this:

```
Array(Array("barfoo"),Array("BARFOO", "FOOFOO"))
```

Tried like this:

> blocks.filter{case (k,v) => v>=3}.keys

It cannot be constructed because the required type needs to be Array[(String, Int)] in order to do filter. I know I am missing the map before but just can't seem to get around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the type of `block` is `Array[Array[(String, Int)]]`, so before using `filter` you need to use `map` operation. Using `block.map(_.filter(_._2 >= 3).map(_._1))` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the elements if the second part of the Tuple is `< 3`:

```
scala> val block = Array(
     |   Array(("foo",0),("bar",1),("foobar",2),("barfoo",3)),
     |   Array(("FOO",0),("BAR",1),("FOOBAR",2),("BARFOO",3),("FOOFOO",4))
     | )
block: Array[Array[(String, Int)]] = Array(Array((foo,0), (bar,1), (foobar,2), (barfoo,3)), Array((FOO,0), (BAR,1), (FOOBAR,2), (BARFOO,3), (FOOFOO,4)))

scala> block.map(_.dropWhile(_._2 < 3).map(_._1).toArray)
res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(barfoo), Array(BARFOO, FOOFOO))
```